# How to design cassandra schema so additional columns can be easily added later?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have defined table structure as defined below,

```
 CREATE TABLE sensor_data (
                asset_id text, 
                event_time timestamp,
                sensor_type int, 
                temperature int, 
                humidity int,
                voltage int,
                co2_percent int
                PRIMARY KEY(asset_id ,event_time)
            ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time ASC)
```

this table captures data coming from a sensor and depending on type of sensor -- column sensor_type, some columns will have a value some others will not. Example temperature only applies to temperature sensor, humidity sensor applies to humidity sensor etc.

Now as I work with more and more sensor my intention is I will simply add additional columns using alter table command. Is this a correct strategy to follow or are there better ways to design this table for future use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered to a similar question few hours ago: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098451/cql3-each-row-to-have-its-own-schema)

Assuming you're Cassandra 2.X ready your situation is easier to handle, to perform what you need I'd use a Map

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_data (
  asset_id text, 
  event_time timestamp,
  sensor_type int, 
  sensor_info map<text, int>,
  PRIMARY KEY(asset_id ,event_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time ASC)
```

Advantages is that your schema will remain the same even if new sensors come into your world. Disadvantage is that you won't be able to retrieve a specific data from your collection, you will always retrieve the collection in its entirely. If you're in Cassandra 2.1 secondary indexes on collections might help.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: That certainly helps and make sense. However when I try to create a index on sensor_type using command - 
CREATE INDEX my_idx ON sensor_info_table KEY(sensor_type);
I am getting error 

<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:41 no viable alternative at input 'KEY'">.

Comment: Indexing on collections is supported only from 2.1 -- what version are you using?

Comment: I am using cassandra from package - apache-cassandra-2.1.0-rc3

Comment: CREATE INDEX my_idx ON sensor_info_table (KEY(sensor_type));
This should work

Comment: I tried that and I get error - 

CREATE INDEX my_idx ON sensor_info_table (KEY(sensor_type));
<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:45 mismatched input '(' expecting ')'">

For it's workth my cqlsh shows version number cqlsh 5.0.1 if that makes difference.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ... KEYS, not KEY

Comment: Yup that works, thank you so much Carlo, and my apologies for not looking into syntax for create index myself.