# Storing schema less data in cassandra

Tags: asp.net, .net, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am creating an application for auditing my web application. so I want to store all audit log in **CASSANDRA** db, and data is not pre-defined that, what we gonna store into db, basically It should be store into a schema less db. so how we can store it into Cassandra. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cassandra is not anymore "schemaless", however using a Map on Cassandra 2.1 you can have a behaviour similar to what you could do in older versions. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098451/cql3-each-row-to-have-its-own-schema) you can find a detailed answer.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: thank you very much Carlo for your help. please help me in this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353213/storing-json-object-in-cassandra