# Storing JSON object in CASSANDRA

Tags: .net, cassandra

I want to store JSON in CASSANDRA db. Each fields of JSON should be mapped to their respective column.

Is it possible ? if possible then how can I achieve it?.

Please help me guys..

Comment: you can store json sting using varchar datatype in cassandra. i am using the same.

Comment: Hi Working Hard, thank you very much for your quick reply, you mean to say the whole JSON string I can store it in a single column. but I want to map each field of JSON to a column in cassandra (one to one mapping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the same given in the other post - Cassandra is no more schema-less so there is no out-of-the-box solution (unless you have a pre-defined json structure). What you could do is to create a first-level json structure into a Map<text, text> (If, as I think, what you need is to select an entry by key)

```
{
  "keya": {
      "keyb": 5,
      "keyc": "somestring"
   },
  "keyd": 3;
}
```

This would be mapped into the following map entries

```
<keya, '{ "keyb": 5, "keyc": "somestring" }'>
<keyd, '3'>
```

In this way you can get the content for any first-level key in the json but you have to search for subsequent entries. You could also "flatten" your keys into a map like this:

```
<keya, '{ "keyb": 5, "keyc": "somestring" }'>
<keya.keyb, '5'>
<keya.keyc": ' "somestring" '>
<keyd, '3'>
```

You might also want insert a custom entry in the map that store the original Json.
In this way you should be able to search for any entry but your map could be much bigger than the original json since it's denormalized to perform key based searches. More: since maps are statically typed you have to map integers, uuid, float or whatever into Strings.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks Carlo. So now I have drooped the idea to use CASSANDRA. now I am going with MongoDB.

Comment: Based on the documentation: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html it is recommended to "keep collections small."  Collections are not meant as a way to implement a schema-less structure.

Comment: Bryce I completely agree: if I am not wrong there is also a 64k size limit per collection. It is not something I encourage is just a technical answer to a specific problem however thanks for having specified it. Carlo