# Storing schema-less complex json object in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have a schema-less json object that I wish to store in Cassandra DB using spring-cassandra. I learned that Cassandra supports Map type but Cassandra doesn't accept `Map<String, Object>` as a data model.

I need to query on the fields of the json so storing it as a blob is out of question. Is there anyway I can do this?

PS: I've looked at [Storing JSON object in CASSANDRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353213/storing-json-object-in-cassandra), the answer didn't seem applicable to my use case as my json could be very complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at UDT (user-defined-type) ?

You can define an UDT like this:

```
CREATE TYPE my_json(
   property1 text,
   property2 int,
   property3 map<text, text>,
   property4 map<int, another_json_type>,
   ...
)
```

And then in Java use `Map<String, UserType>`

Note: `UserType` comes from the Java driver: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/UserType.java

You cannot create an user type n Java, you can only get it from the metadata of your table, see this: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0/driver-core/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/core/UserTypesTest.java#L62-L81

Answer (score 0):

1) one solution from me is, integrate solr search and index this table first.

2) Later write a solr analyser to parse the json and put under various fields in solr while indexing.

3) Next step is use solr supported query like select * from table where solr_query = "{search expression syntax}"