# Access cassandra map element

Tags: cassandra

From the documentation, it seems like we should be able to query individual map elements:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_map_t.html

> Each element of the map is internally stored as one Cassandra column
>   that you can modify, replace, delete, and query.

The examples show updating individual elements, but similar syntax doesn't seem to work for select statements. Is there a way to select only one key-value for a map column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not retrieve part of a collection: even if internally each entry of a map is stored as a column you can only retrieve the whole collection

Comment: That's what I thought. Unfortunate. You can update parts, but only querying parts is still a no.

Comment: You can query a collection to know if it contains something but you can not retrieve only a portion of the collection

Comment: Could you give an example of the former?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098451/cql3-each-row-to-have-its-own-schema

Comment: So said. I do some research, only find a way to do this is to use the UDF. [Accessing Cassandra Map values](https://davefelcey.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/accessing-cassandra-map-values/)